# Backup Hyper-V To Google Drive?

Tags: backup, hyper-v, virtual-machines, cloud, vhd

I was thinking about backing up a Hyper-V host to the cloud and a potentially crazy idea came to mind.

With Google Drive, you can get 1TB of storage for 2 bucks a month. This would be more than sufficient to backup all of my VMs.

Is this a good idea for machines that don't contain critical / highly confidential information?

I am running Hyper-V Core 2012 R2. How would I go about doing this, if I were to ignore all warnings?

An Issue I see with this is that does GD even support incremental backups of a VHDX file or will it just sync over the whole drive again?

Thanks.

Comment: What would the restore process look like? How long would a restore take? Are these VM's mission critical to the business? What's your RTO and RPO for these VM's?

Comment: Why not use Azure backup services?

Comment: *does GD even support incremental backups of a VHDX file* - why not ask them? Their support people are just as entitled to see good comedy writing as we are. I'm willing to bet that neither Google or Microsoft would consider that to be a tested or supported scenario...

Comment: To correct the OP, Google Drive charges $9.99/mo for a TB, and $1.99 for 100 GB.

Comment: Voting to close. This is not a valid approach as per: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow. - only VERY Unprofessional people would consider somehow hammering a backup scenario like this. hyper-V has perfect cloud capable backup tools without referring to private cloud storage offers.

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned above, it's not state-of the art but you could do [Export-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/export-vm?view=win10-ps) in a scheduled task if google drive is visible from the core hyper-v, with a drive letter. 
It appears you can mount google drive as a drive letter using [subst](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html).

Let me know if you need assistance with the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR - this would be a bad plan for a business.

Each sync would be a full sync.  Backing up the VHDX file will backup the data, but it isn't a full VM backup.  If you restored over the existing VHDX you wouldn't notice, but if you had to restore to a new server, you'd lose the VM configuration.

If you just need a point in time, you could do an export from within Hyper-V to get the data and configuration.

You might look at a product like Veeam to create the backups to another server and sync those to Google for an offsite.